# Glyphicons Pro icon not showing correctly in Rails 4.2/Bootstrap

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

After purchasing Glyphicons online, I integrate the `glyphicons regular` with Bootstrap (3.3.6) into Rails 4.2 app. Before that `glyphicon halfings` has been integrated by someone else.

What I did was to copy 5 Glyphicon files (`svg, ttf, eot, woff, woff2`) to `glyphicons/web/bootstrap-example/fonts/` to `assets/fonts/`. Also copied is `plyphicons/web/bootstrap-example/css/glyphicons.css` to `assets/stylesheets/'.

Here are the files under Rails assets:

[image]

The problem is that the icon in `glyphicon regular` not showing.

In `application.css.scss`, add `@import glyphicons.css`

The problem is that the glyphicon are not showing correctly. Here is the herb codel:

```
<%= link_to '<i class="glyphicons glyphicons-eye-open"></i> Free Trial Now'.html_safe,... %>
```

It is showing a box with char (can't read) in 4 corners. See image below:
[image]

What's missing in our process?

Comment: can you show me the console error if there is, and the element in html ( f12, check elements...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since stylesheet is under `/assets` in Rails. In `glyphicon.css`, `fonts` need to be replaced with `assets`. After this change, glyphicon PRO starts working!

Answer (score 1):

Well, the first thing you should do is to open the browser debug console (Ctrl+shift+i in chrome) and list out the errors that causing this bug.

Normally there are always some image references in the third party .css files.
And when you integrate those files you need to change the image url/path according to the need.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

this is correct method to use glyphicons into the link

```
 <td><%= link_to edit_user_path(user) do %>
         <i class="glyphicons glyphicons-eye-open" title='Edit'></i>
        <% end %>
     </td>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do other things to work,

Check this tutorial: 
http://www.erikminkel.com/2013/09/01/twitter-bootstrap-3-in-a-rails-4-application/

Comment: The issue is how to add glyphicon PRO. glyphicon halfling has been working in the app.

Comment: You dont have glyphicon PRO bundle inside bootstrap. The halflings are inside already though. In order to show those, you need to check that the css hexadecimal codes are good to go.